# .yas-parents have no effect with web-mode

Tags: yasnippet, web-mode

I'm using web-mode and yasnippet for coding PHP and HTML.

To use yasnippet in web-mode, will have to install php-mode, php-auto-yasnippets, emmet-mode and ac-emmet as suggested in web-mode.org. But I prefer to make it happen just with web-mode and yasnippet.

Part of my web-mode configuration is like this:

```
(defadvice yas-expand-from-trigger-key (before web-mode-before-yas-expand activate)
        (run-hooks 'web-mode-cur-language-mode-hook))


(add-hook 'web-mode-cur-language-mode-hook
      '(lambda ()
         (let ((web-mode-cur-language
                (web-mode-language-at-pos)))
           (if (string= web-mode-cur-language "php")
               (yas-activate-extra-mode 'php-mode)
             (yas-deactivate-extra-mode 'php-mode))
           (if (string= web-mode-cur-language "html")
                (yas-activate-extra-mode 'html-mode)
              (yas-deactivate-extra-mode 'html-mode))
           )))
```

And following is my yasnippet configuration:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path (expand-file-name "elpa/yasnippet" user-emacs-directory))

(require 'yasnippet)

(yas-global-mode 1)
```

It works very well when edit php file in web-mode.

Then open a html file in emacs, input "form" then "tab", everything works fine. But if input "href" then "tab", nothing happened. It supposed to call the "href" snippet in nxml-mode as written in html-mode's .yas-parents.

How could I make this right? I really don't want copy all those snippets from nxml-mode to html-mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code changes was made to yasnippet.el (with 1 addition and 2 deletions), to let it find parents for extra-modes too. Here is the link [fix #619](https://github.com/npostavs/yasnippet/commit/603c2949b687c34adbfc8d151e01076995ff6392)

Around line 744:

```
                     append (funcall dfs neighbour explored)))))
 (remove-duplicates (if mode
                        (funcall dfs mode)
-                    (append yas--extra-modes
-                            (funcall dfs major-mode))))))
+                    (apply #'append (mapcar dfs (cons major-mode yas--extra-modes)))))))
```

Comment: Please make this a complete answer by putting the necessary code in the post rather than just a link.

Comment: Sorry about that, made another answer, is that OK now?

Comment: please edit your original post rather than posting a new answer.  Also, please clarify what one is supposed to do.  It's hard to tell what the answer is without more explanation.

Comment: Roger. Edited the original answer. I'm new to stackechange, sorry for the blurred answer before, and thanks for your advice.

Comment: Not a problem. Thanks for updating.

Comment: By the way, I ended up applying a slightly different fix to Yasnippet. [#621](https://github.com/capitaomorte/yasnippet/pull/621)

Comment: I tried the new version, it works fine now :)